# Entity Component System (ECS) in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection, entity-component-system

While trying to write a game engine, I came up with this ECS / Component Based Architecture for its physics and drawing logic. I want to get some feedback on its architecture. I am using reflection inside the querying code and to get a class's superclass. Is this bad design in this case?

Note that I left out most documentation as most of the code should be self explanatory.

My solution is not strictly an ECS as Entities are not just pointers to blocks of components *(in this version I added a `name` field just to clarify that)*. I decided to go that route as Component Arrays would not be stored contiguously anyways, which is a limitation imposed by Java *(Looking forward to Project Valhalla)*.

I took inspiration from Unity's GameObjects, difference being that you have to pass a Class as an argument instead of giving the type as a type parameter *(again, this is a limitation imposed by Java)*. In the Scene class I have a method called `forEach(...)` which gets a type of a query *(just a record)* and a function consuming the query and its matching GameObject as parameters.

In the example I use `Position` and `Velocity` to form a very basic Physics System operating on them (via `PhysicsQuery`). The system simply prints the matching GameObject and updates its position afterwards. In this example you can also see that inheritance of components works (`PhysicsQuery` queries `Position` but also matches with GameObjects having a `Position3D` component).

**Example.java**

```java
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scene scene = new Scene();
        scene.addObject(new GameObject("Object A",
                new Position3D(0, 0, 0), new Velocity(1, 0)));
        scene.addObject(
                new GameObject("Object B", new Position(0, 1)));

        record PhysicsQuery(Position position,
                Velocity velocity) {
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            scene.forEach(PhysicsQuery.class,
                    (query, gameObject) -> {
                        System.out.println(gameObject);
                        query.position.x += query.velocity.x();
                        query.position.y += query.velocity.y();
                    });
    }
}

class Position {
    public float x;
    public float y;

    public Position(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Position{" + "x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "}";
    }
}

class Position3D extends Position {
    public float z;

    public Position3D(float x, float y, float z) {
        super(x, y);
        this.z = z;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Position3D{" + "x=" + x + ", y=" + y + ", z="
                + z + "}";
    }
}

record Velocity(float x, float y) {
}
```

**Scene.java**

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.RecordComponent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Scene {
    public List<GameObject> getGameObjects() {
        return gameObjects;
    }

    private static <T extends Record> Function<Object[], T> getRecordConstructor(
            Class<T> type) {
        var recordComponents = type.getRecordComponents();
        try {
            Constructor<T> constructor = type
                    .getDeclaredConstructor(
                            Arrays.stream(recordComponents)
                                    .map(RecordComponent::getType)
                                    .toArray(Class<?>[]::new));
            constructor.setAccessible(true);
            return (arguments) -> {
                try {
                    return constructor.newInstance(arguments);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException
                        | InvocationTargetException
                        | InstantiationException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(
                            "Could not construct record", e);
                }
            };
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Canonical constructor not found", e);
        }
    }

    private final List<GameObject> gameObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    public <T extends GameObject> T addObject(T gameObject) {
        gameObjects.add(gameObject);
        return gameObject;
    }

    public <T extends GameObject> boolean removeObject(
            T gameObject) {
        return gameObjects.remove(gameObject);
    }

    /**
     * Call a function on all objects that have all components
     * specified by {@code type}'s fields
     * 
     * @param type
     *          Type of a query
     * @param consumer
     *          Called on matching Objects
     */
    public <T extends Record> void forEach(Class<T> type,
            BiConsumer<T, GameObject> consumer) {
        var constructor = getRecordConstructor(type);
        for (var gameObject : gameObjects) {
            T query = gameObject.toQuery(type, constructor);
            if (query != null)
                consumer.accept(query, gameObject);
        }
    }

}
```

**GameObject.java**

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class GameObject {
    private final Map<Class<?>, Deque<Object>> components = new HashMap<>();
    private String name;

    public GameObject(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public GameObject(String name, Object... components) {
        this.name = name;
        addComponents(components);
    }

    private void addComponent(Class<?> type,
            Object component) {
        components
                .computeIfAbsent(type, k -> new ArrayDeque<>())
                .add(component);
    }

    private boolean removeComponent(Class<?> type,
            Object component) {
        var componentsOfType = components.get(type);
        if (componentsOfType == null)
            return false;
        boolean result = componentsOfType.remove(component);
        if (componentsOfType.size() == 0) {
            components.remove(type);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean isUserDefined(Class<?> type) {
        return type != Object.class && type != Record.class
                && type != Enum.class;
    }

    public GameObject addComponent(Object component) {
        Class<?> type = component.getClass();
        do {
            addComponent(type, component);
            type = type.getSuperclass();
        } while (type != null && isUserDefined(type));
        return this;
    }

    public GameObject addComponents(Object... components) {
        for (var component : components) {
            addComponent(component);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public <T> T removeComponent(T component) {
        Class<?> type = component.getClass();
        do {
            removeComponent(type, component);
            type = type.getSuperclass();
        } while (type != null && isUserDefined(type));
        return component;
    }

    public <T> T getComponent(Class<T> type) {
        var componentsOfType = components.get(type);
        if (componentsOfType == null)
            return null;
        return type.cast(componentsOfType.peekFirst());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> Collection<T> getComponents(Class<T> type) {
        return (Collection<T>) components.get(type);
    }

    /**
     * Process this object to a query of components.
     * 
     * @param query
     *          Class of a record containing the wanted
     *          components
     * @param generator
     *          a function that gets all the components in the
     *          order defined by the {@code query} and results
     *          in an instance of {@code query}
     * @return an instance of the {@code query} iff this
     *         object has all components wanted by it, null
     *         otherwise
     */
    public <T extends Record> T toQuery(Class<T> query,
            Function<Object[], T> generator) {
        var recordComponents = query.getRecordComponents();
        var components = new Object[recordComponents.length];
        for (int i = 0,
                length = recordComponents.length; i < length; ++i) {
            var componentType = recordComponents[i].getType();
            var component = getComponent(componentType);
            if (component == null)
                return null; // component not found -> return null
            components[i] = component;
        }
        // All components were found -> call generator with them
        return generator.apply(components);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GameObject{" + "name=" + "'" + name + "'"
                + ", components=" + components + "}";
    }
}
```

Comment: While I can't give you any feedback directly, why don't you try to look at the source of [Ashley](https://github.com/libgdx/ashley)? It's an existing ECS used by libGDX, maybe it'll give you some more ideas or insights for your project.